# Direct Recursion printStars

Tags: java, recursion

```
public static void printStars(int lines) {
    int j;

    if(lines>0) {
        for(j=0;j<lines;j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();

        printStars(lines -1);

        for(j=0;j<lines;j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

I'm trying to understand how the second for loop works. From my understanding the first loop will run until the `j` is less than `3` and the method will call itself and you will get. `lines==2` and print two stars and print `1` star for last call.

```
*** 
**
*
```

But for the second for loop why does it print

```
* 
** 
***
```

if `(lines-1)==2`, shouldn't it be?

```
**
*
```

Is there some special reason why the code changes so much by just moving the order of the recursive statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remember recursive method calls continues execution where it stops see blow, let say you pass `lines=3`

```
printStars(3) // stops with lines = 3  , prints ***
 printStars(2) // stops with lines = 2 , prints **
  printStars(1) // stops with lines = 1 , prints *
   printStars(0)  // prints nothing as no for condition is satisfied
  printStars(1)  // starts where it stops with lines = 1 and proceeds to second for loop,  prints *
 printStars(2)  // starts where it stops with lines = 2 and proceeds to second for loop, prints **
printStars(3)  // starts where it stops with lines = 3 and proceeds to second for loop, prints ***
```

Comment: I just don't understand why is lines going from 1-2-3. Is it because 1+1=2+1=3? Because in the code there is no increment of lines.

Comment: No. because as you may be aware recursive function call can be taken as a stack, LIFO( first in last out) . we firs call `printStars(3)` (note this call is not yet finished)followed by `printStars(2)`(note this call is not yet finished), and then `printStars(1)`. so when `printStars(1)` finishes `printStars(2)` follows at it is on the top of the stack followed by `printStars(3)`

Comment: remember the method calls are stopping at the line `printStars(lines -1);` because it is another a method call, so they will continue from that line when next function call returns.

Answer (score 1):

Showing call stack as indentations:

```
call to printStars(3):
  prints "***"
  call to printStars(2):
    prints "**"
    call to printStars(1):
      prints "*"
      call to printStars(0):
        does nothing
      end of call
      prints "*"
    end of call
    prints "**"
  end of call
  prints "***"
end of call
```

Comment: would printStars(0) not be possible because the if loop only runs when lines>0? Also for the prints after printStars(0) does the "*" add on themselves in the print statement?

Comment: @shivalph Don't understand your comment. --- `printStars(0)` *is* possible, and does nothing, since that's what it's coded to do. --- What did you mean by *"does the "*" add on themselves"*? You have 2 `for` loops that each print `lines` number of stars on a single line. The first loop prints stars before recursive call, and the second loop prints stars after the recursive call.

Comment: My question didn't make sense know that I look back and it but I understand it now.